# ng-lazyload-image not load on scroll on ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, lazy-loading

I have an ionic 2 project and I am using ng-lazyload-image. My problem is that when I scroll the screen the images are not showed, but I can see in the network that they are downloaded, so probably my scroll event is not firing.

Here is my page html code:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Profile</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="profileInfo" [hidden]="!dataLoaded" id="container" padding>
  <div class="profileDetails">
    <div *ngIf="showSection === 'following'">
      Following
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="showSection === 'followers'">
      Followers
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="showSection === 'my-stories'">
        <story-summary *ngFor="let story of myStories" [story]="story" (click)="readStory(story)"></story-summary>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="showSection === 'saved-stories'">
      <story-summary *ngFor="let story of savedStories" [story]="story"></story-summary>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="showSection === 'draft-stories'">
      <story-summary *ngFor="let story of dradtStories" [story]="story"></story-summary>
    </div>
  </div>


</ion-content>
```

The summary-component.ts file:

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Component, Input, ElementRef, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Story } from "../story.model";
import { Profile } from "../../user/profile/profile.model";
import { ReadStoryPage } from "../../../pages/story/read/read";

@Component({
  selector: 'story-summary',
  templateUrl: 'summary.component.html'
})
export class StorySummaryComponent {

  @Input() story: Story = <Story>{ user: <Profile>{} };

  private lazyLoadingImage = "assets/img/spinner-loading.gif";

    constructor(private _DomSanitizer: DomSanitizer, 
               private navCtrl: NavController,
               private elmRef: ElementRef) 
    { }

    getProfilePicture() {
      let image: any = 'assets/img/avatar-black.png';
      if (this.story.user) {
        if (this.story.user.mapporiaImage) {
          image = this._DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.story.user.mapporiaImage);
        } else if (this.story.user.facebookImage) {
          image = this._DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.story.user.facebookImage);
        }
      }
      return image;
    }

    getUsername() {
      let username = 'unknown';
      if (this.story.user && this.story.user.nickName) {
        username = this.story.user.nickName;
      }
      return username;
    }

    getRating() {
      let rating;
      if (this.story.rating) {
        // TODO: calculate story rating
      }
      return rating;
    }
}
```

And the HTML for summary.component.ts:

```
<div class="story">
    <img [src]="getProfilePicture()" alt="Alt text" id="profile-picture" />
    <span>{{getUsername()}}</span>
    <span>{{story.location}}</span>
    <span>{{story.time}}</span>
    <span>{{getRating()}}</span>
    <span>{{story.subject}}</span>
    <div *ngFor="let image of story.images">
        <div>
            <img [src]="lazyLoadingImage"
                 [lazyLoad]="image"
                 [offset]="500"
                 [scrollObservable]="container"
                 class="thumnails"     
                 alt="Story Image"
                 id="story-image" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also downloaded the examples form git, and tried to modifies my code, but still can't get it to work.
The images are loaded at the top of the page, the spinners is here, but when I scroll the screen, the spinners are not replaced by the image, and the images are downloded.

thnx

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `src` for `defaultImage`, such as:

```
<img [defaultImage]="lazyLoadingImage"
                 [lazyLoad]="image"
                 [offset]="500"
                 [scrollObservable]="container.ionScroll" // Try also `container.ionScroll` instead of just `container`
                 class="thumnails"     
                 alt="Story Image"
                 id="story-image" />
```

Comment: tried already, that was the original settings, and not works
is it possible that I am putting the #container at the wrong place!?